# How to select multiple condition in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have like following table

```
type value
A   true
A   false
B   true
B   false
C   true
C   true
```

and I would like to get following result
first type `A` or `B` must be selected, then type `B` and value `true` must be dropped

```
type value
A    true
A    false
B    false
```

I tried like following query

```
select *
from table
where type in ('A','B')
and (type,value) not in ('B','true')
```

but it returned like following error
`arguments of row IN must all be row expressions;`

What is the wrong point of this?
Are there any way to achieve this?

If someone has opinion, please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE type = 'A' OR type = 'B' AND value = false;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6b8974a21e8082253b6d6ee69ecc5556) of the above query.

Comment: Presumably, the precedence is on the `AND`, so it is effectively doing: `WHERE type = 'A' OR (type = 'B' AND value = false)`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Correct.  I omit the parentheses for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Make this a tuple by adding double paranthesis on the right side on the equal to sign

PFB corrected query

```
select *
from table
where type in ('A','B')
and (type,value) not in (('B','true'))
```